# How can I access a JWT token implicitly in .Net Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core, jwt

I'm starting to learn about JWT and developing an angular app which uses Firebase to authenticate users.

Since the JWT token is sent in requests that need to be authorized I was wondering if I can access it and decode it somehow without explicitly setting it as a parameter?

Here is some code that uses JWT for Authorization

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Policy = Policies.Admin)]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateVehicle([FromBody]SaveVehicleResource vehicleResource)
{
        //How can I access the JWT token and decode it to get the user uid?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I access the JWT token and decode it to get the user uid?

I'm failing to understand why you'd need to access a JWT token to get the user id because the `HttpContext` object already exposes the current `principal` for a request as the `User` property. ASP.NET core also doesn't send a JWT token on each request. It sends the encrypted authentication cookie that was created when the user signed in and it simply contains the claims from that JWT token.

The `principal` is the current user, implemented as ClaimsPrincipal. It contains a
collection of Claims that describe said user and contains the users' ID as well as other claims that it got from the Identity Provider.

If we are in a controller that inherits from the Controller and ControllerBase
base classes, then we can access the User principal like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Policy = Policies.Admin)]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateVehicle([FromBody]SaveVehicleResource vehicleResource)
{
        var userId =  User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
}
```